# How to detect whether my Go code is running on Raspberry Pi and which architecture

Tags: go

I'm using this code to differentiate the platform my application is running on:

```golang
import (
    "runtime"
)

func Get() (string, error) {
    // Detect platform we are running on.
    if runtime.GOOS == "windows" {
        // ...
    } else if runtime.GOOS == "darwin" {
        // ...
    } else if runtime.GOOS == "linux" {
        // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

Now, I intend to detect whether my application is running on Raspberry Pi and if so, which architecture, i.e. ARM, x86, ...

What's the most reliable to do so? Any standard practice which I might be missing?

Comment: Usually, you use build tags (`//go:build linux && arm64`). If you want to detect on runtime, you can use `runtime.GOARCH` and `runtime.GOOS`, but usually that doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try reading Raspberry Pi serial number. For example, [https://linuxhint.com/find-serial-number-raspberry-pi/#:~:text=Your%20device%20serial%20number%20is,the%20content%20of%20the%20file](https://linuxhint.com/find-serial-number-raspberry-pi/#:%7E:text=Your%20device%20serial%20number%20is,the%20content%20of%20the%20file).

Alex

Comment: Thanks :) So, basically I can run these commands and if the output is not an empty string, then the code is running on R-Pi:
Either:

```bash
cat /sys/firmware/devicetree/base/serial-number
```

Or:

```bash
cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep Serial
```
So, the serial is only available for R-Pi devices, right? If so, that might be a reliable solution =)

Comment: Correct. And each RPI has different and unique serial number. And you don't need to run external commands - you can just open file and read file contents with any Go io functoins, like os.Open or io/ioutil.ReadFile.

Comment: Makes sense. Looks great =)